# How to read Drop-down selected index id?

Tags: drop-down-menu, dart, flutter, dropdown

I added the DropDownButton. It's working well. Data coming from the cache.
**How to get selected description id(id mean `i`)**

```
Future<List<DataWorkTypes>> displayWorkTypes() async {
    var db = await db1;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('WorkTypesTable');

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return DataWorkTypes(i: maps[i]['i'], d: maps[i]['d']);
    });
  }
```

> I need to get `i`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    getWorkTypes().then((result) {
      setState(() {
        workTypes = result;
      });
    });
  }

  Future getWorkTypes() async {
    List workType = (await HelperDatabase1().displayWorkTypes());
    for (int i = 0; i < workType.length; i++) {
      workTypes.add(workType[i].d);
    }
    return workTypes;
  }



Container(
            child: ButtonTheme(
              alignedDropdown: true,
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                isExpanded: true,
                value: _workTypes,
                items: workTypes.map((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(
                      value,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _workTypes = value),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the index of the selection by using the `indexOf()` function of a `List`. For example, given your code:

```
onChanged: (value) {
  int index = workTypes.indexOf(value);
  setState(() => _workTypes = value);
},
```

Just be aware that `indexOf()` returns the index of the **first** matching element from the list, so if you have duplicate Strings you will get the wrong index.

## Edit after question clarification

A `DropdownMenuItem` can take the value of an object and still display just a `String`. For your code above, start by changing the type of `_workTypes` to `DataWorkTypes` and `workTypes` to `List<DataWorkTypes>`. Your code would end up looking roughly like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  HelperDatabase1().displayWorkTypes().then((result) {
    setState(() {
      workTypes = result;
    });
  });
}

child: DropdownButton<DataWorkTypes>(
  isExpanded: true,
  value: _workTypes,
  items: workTypes.map((DataWorkTypes value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<DataWorkTypes>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(
        value.d, // same label as before
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
    int index = value.i; // here is your index
    _workTypes = value;
  }),
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
),
```